# Aligning TextViews in same row

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have two `TextViews` aligned in the same row. If text in both `TextViews` are small, they fit in same row in the screen. But if the text in the left `TextView` (`employee name`) increases, the text in the right `TextView` (`employee type`) is shifted to the second line, but to the right side of the screen. How do I make the second `TextView` aligned to the left and in the second line (below `employee name`) if the `employee name` in left `TextView` is increased and both `TextViews` do not fit in same row?

Please check the below screenshot : 
[image: current behaviour]

Please find my code below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#fff"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/employee_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22.0sp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/employee_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/employee_name"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/employee_name"
    android:textSize="15.0sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: give single line true and max lines 1 in the layout

Comment: Why do you use 2 Textviews?

Comment: @Nava2011 : thanks for your input. it is wrapping text into one line. but is there a way to shift it to second line just below the first textview. i need to display entire text.

Comment: @ ZerO : i need 2 textviews since they have different fonts and text size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use a single `TextView`, and modify the characteristics using Spans.

Assuming you only had the `TextView` with `@+id/employee_name`:

```
TextView employeeInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employee_name);

String employeeName = // get your employee name
String employeeType = // get your employee type

// Assuming you move your 15sp into a dimens.xml resource file
int employeeTypeSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.employee_type_text_size);

SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(employeeName);
builder.append(employeeType);

// Set the smaller text size from the end of the name to the end
// of the string.
builder.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(employeeTypeSize), 
                employeeName.length(), builder.length(), 
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Then set this spannable to the TextView
employeeInfo.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest one of the following:

1. Always place the employee type on the second line, to avoid problems like this.
2. Find some other way to indicate the employee that doesn't involve spelling out the type. For example, perhaps use some kind of symbol that doesn't take up so much space. That way even if the name gets very long, you can still leave room for a small symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#fff"
  android:weightSum="2"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/employee_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textSize="22.0sp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/employee_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:textSize="15.0sp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```